# UITableView inside UIViewControllerView unexpected margins

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, constraints, xib

I have normal `UIViewController` on my storyboard with a standard `UIView` which contains only one child - `UITableView`

When adding constraints between `UIView` and `UITableView` ( equal widths, equla heights, vertical space 0 top layout guide, horizontal space 0 for leading margin ) as a result my table view should fill it's parent.

Instead my table view appears to have left and top margins (16 and 64). The `Size Inspector` shows that the table views `Alignment Rectangle` is as follows x=16,y=64,width=600,height=600 although all my constraints have constants set to 0's. When I try to edit manually `Alignment Rectangle` I keep getting `Misplaced Views` warnig which try to restore previous values.

Any I idea what might be the cause of this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the view you want to remove margins. Open `Contraint Editor` uncheck `Prefer Margin relative`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. It was solved by deselecting `Under Top Bars` under `Extend Edges` in the properties of the topmost UIViewController in storyboard.